# Bring phonegap 3 Android app to foreground

Tags: cordova, foreground

Is there a plugin to bring android apps from background to foreground in phonegap 3+?

Thank you,

Juan.

Comment: I think the question is absolutely fine and straight to the point. What other details do you need?? It's about PhoneGap, it's about Android, and it's about how to bring an app, which has been put to the background, to the foreground. Plus it's regarding PhoneGap 3+. Now, I just basically repeated what he asked about. Is anything unclear? :)